# Stack below the AppBar and not behind

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I cant seem to find the answer to this simple problem but I dont understand why my Stack is BELOW the appbar and not BEHIND it.  Also, this is a custom appbar

What Im trying to achieve: The image should be BEHIND the appbar and not below it, meaning the appbar will overlap the image or is in front of the image

my code for this is this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Hero(
                  tag: widget.discount.name,
                  child: ShadowClip(
                    clipper: CircularClipper(),
                    shadow: Shadow(blurRadius: 0.0),
                    child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                      placeholder: 'assets/images/placeholder.png',
                      height: 200.0,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: widget.discount.imageUrl.Url,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              // Positioned(
              //   top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0,
              //   child: DetailPageAppbar(height:60),
              // ),
              ],
            ),
```

[image]

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: The image should be BEHIND the appbar and not below it, meaning the appbar will overlap the image or is in front of the image

Comment: Wrap your Hero widget with a container widget  and not need to use appbar below container put your back arrow code simple :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below code and check output

```
  SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 1,
        leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: NetworkImage(
                                "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9")))),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 6,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 50,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int pos) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text("121"),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
```

[image]

Comment: Works for me but didnt scroll but I fixed it using a Single child scroll

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: Header(),
        //...
     }   //end method build

PreferredSize Header() {
   return PreferredSize(
     preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(56.0),    //default appbar height (material design principles)
     child: Container(
        color: Colors.Transparent,
        child: Center(
          child: Text("APPBAR TEXT"),
        ), 
      ),
   );

}  //end method Header
```